# How to include an html file into a template using App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I used to add my templates like `hedaer.html` and `footer.html` in django projects with `{% include 'header.html' %}`

i have do the same in my App Engine project but got this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 1294: invalid continuation byte
```

I wonder if there is a way to do that In App Engine template using Python ?

html files created with UTF-8 encode:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly how you include an html file in a template. The error simply means the html file you are trying to include is not UTF-8 valid. All you need to do is re-save it as UTF-8 in your editor.

Comment: my file is exactly in utf-8 : `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: The meta tag tells the browser what encoding the content on the page is in but it does not magically convert that content into that encoding. I would still first make sure your html file is saved in UTF-8 format and only then see if there are any other issues. So, say you're using Sublime Text, you'd go to "File" -> "Save with Encoding".

Comment: I have edited the post: the html files are initially created with utf-8

Comment: finally you are right, the file was not enregistred utf-8 i have checked all my files with include statement and get the one which has the problem (not created in the editor but copied) thanks.